Confusion about one initial/boundary value problem for heat equation
This is a follow-up question to this. The referenced question arose while I was trying to solve
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = \frac{1}{2} \Delta u, & x \in X, \\
u ( 0, x ) = 1, & x \in X, \\
u ( t, x ) = 0, & x \in \partial X, \\
X = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ x_1 > 1, x_2 > 1 \}. &
\end{cases}
$$
I tried rewriting this problem in the following coordinates:
$$
\begin{cases}
a = \min \{ x_1, x_2 \}, \\
s = \max \{ x_1, x_2 \}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\Delta$ has the same expression in terms of $a$ and $s$, that is,
$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}.
$$
The domain $X$ may be described as $X = \{ a < 1 \}$, and its boundary is given by $\partial X = \{ a = 1 \}$. The separation of variables leads to
$$
\begin{cases}
-f''(a) = \lambda^2 f(a), \\
f(1) = 0, \\
f \ \text{is bounded}
\end{cases}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{cases}
-g''(s) = \mu^2 g(s) \\
g \ \text{is bounded}.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, the solution of the initial problem should be of the form
$$
u(t, a, s) = \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} \sin \lambda (1-a) \ e^{i \omega s} \varphi ( t, \lambda, \omega ) \, d\lambda \, d\omega
$$
with some $\varphi(t, \omega, \lambda)$ which is yet to be determined.
Trying to satisfy the heat equation lead me to
$$
\varphi(t, \omega, \lambda) = e^{-(\lambda^2 + \omega^2) \, t / 2} \, \varphi ( \lambda, \omega ).
$$
The Dirichlet condition is automatically satisfied, and it remains to enforce
$$
1 = \int_0^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} \sin \lambda ( 1 - a ) \, e^{i \omega s} \, \varphi(\lambda, \omega) \, d\lambda \, d\omega.
$$
Solving this equation was the subject of my previous question. There, I received a suggestion to try
$$
\varphi(\lambda, \omega) = -\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\delta(\omega)}{\lambda}.
$$
This does give the desired result, and the resulting solution is given by
$$
u ( t, a, s ) 
= \operatorname{erf} \left( \frac{1-a}{\sqrt{2t}} \right)
\implies
u ( t, x ) = \operatorname{erf} \left( \frac{1-\min \{ x_1, x_2 \}}{\sqrt{2t}} \right).
$$
What bothers me is that

this solution does not depend on $x_2$ as long as $x_1 < x_2$, my intuition tells me that it shouldn't be the case
this solution is non-smooth near $\{ x_1 = x_2 \}$
if I compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2} \Delta u$ in the distributional sense, not everything cancels and I am left with some delta-functions

So, my question is this: what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

It seems that
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2} \Delta u
= -\frac{
e^{ -( 1 - \min \{ x_1, x_2 \} )^2 / 2t }
}{
\sqrt{2 \pi t}
} \Big(
\delta( x_1 - x_2 ) + \delta ( x_2 - x_1 )
\Big),
$$
unless I made a calculation mistake. Maybe this equation is possible to solve and then subtract from the solution obtained above?

Numerical solution of the equation is clearly different:


Another approach I found it to shift the domain to $0$, that is, to study the same problem in $\hat{X} = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ x > 0, y > 0 \}$ and use the conformal invariance of $\Delta$ with the following map:
$$
f \colon \hat{X} \to \mathbb{C}_+ \colon z \mapsto -z^2. 
$$
Then the Laplacian changes as follows:
$$
\Delta_z \leadsto 
|f'(z)|^{-2} \Delta
= \frac{1}{4\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \, \Delta,
$$
and we the problem becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = \frac{1}{8 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \Delta u, & x \in \mathbb{C}_+, \\
u ( 0, x, y ) = 1, & x \in \mathbb{C}_+, \\
u ( t, x, 0 ) = 0, & x \in \mathbb{C}_+.
\end{cases}
$$
Unfortunately, I don't know how to construct solutions of
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\Delta u}{8 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.
$$

When you transform co-ordinates, you need things like $\partial_{x_1}a=\partial_{x_1}\min{{x_1,x_2}}$ which already shows you will have problems. Rather: find the Dirichlet Green's function for a point source in the plane, then use it to create the Green's function for your problem by the method of images

@Sal, Green function for a point source is standard, but where do I put the sources to satisfy the Dirichlet condition in this domain? I'm interested, because this solution would be simpler than what I wrote below...

So, solving this question via conformal invariance turned out to be quite doable. Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ via $z = x + i y$ and letting $\xi = f(z) = ( e^{-i \pi/2} ( z - (1+i) ) )^{2/3}$ be  the conformal map between $X$ and the upper half-plane $H$, we note that
$$
\Delta_z 
= |f'(z) |^2 \, \Delta_\xi
= \left| \frac{2}{3} e^{-i \pi/3} ( z - (1+i) )^{-1/3} \right|^2 \, \Delta_\xi
= \frac{4}{9} \left| ( \xi^{3/2} )^{-1/3} \right|^2 \, \Delta_\xi
= \frac{4}{9|\xi|} \, \Delta_\xi,
$$
where $\Delta_z$ and $\Delta_\xi$ are defined by $4 \partial_z \partial_{\bar z}$ and $4 \partial_\xi \partial_{\bar \xi}$ correspondingly. Hence, instead of the original problem in $X$, we may the following problem in $H$
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = \frac{1}{2} \, \frac{4}{9r} \, \Delta \, u, & (x,y) \in H, \\
u (0, x, y) = 1, & (x, y) \in H, \\
u (t, x, 0) = 0, & x \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here $r = |\xi| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then the solution of the original problem is given by rewriting the solution of this problem in the original variables.
To solve this problem, we shall first find an eigensystem of $\Delta/r$. $r$ suggests we try polar coordinates:
$$
\frac{1}{r} \, \Delta f = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^3} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \varphi^2} = -\lambda^2 f, \quad
f ( r, 0 ) = f(r, \pi) = 0.
$$
The variables separate, so we can look for an eigensystem of the form $f(r, \varphi) = R(r) \Phi(\varphi)$. These two functions must solve
$$
\begin{cases}
\Phi''(\varphi) = -\mu^2 \Phi(\varphi), \\
\Phi(0) = \Phi ( \pi ) = 0
\end{cases}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{cases}
r^2 R''(r) + r R'(r) + ( \lambda^2 r^3 - \mu^2 ) R(r) = 0, \\
R(t) \ \text{is bounded}.
\end{cases}
$$
The first gives $\Phi(\varphi) = \sin k \varphi$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. The second gives $R ( r ) = J_{2k/3} ( 2 \lambda r^{3/2} / 3 )$, because the second solution $J_{-2k/3} ( 2 \lambda r^{3/2} / 3 )$ is unbounded at $0$. Therefore, $u(t, r, \varphi)$ is of the form
$$
u ( t, r, \varphi ) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin(k \varphi)
\int_0^\infty J_{2k/3} \left( \frac{2 \lambda}{3} \, r^{3/2} \right)
\psi_k(t, \lambda) \, d \lambda,
$$
where $\psi_k(t, \lambda)$ is the new unknown function. First, we try to satisfy the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{2}{9 r} \Delta u
\implies
\frac{\partial \psi_k}{\partial t} = -\frac{2 \lambda^2}{9} \, \psi_k,
$$
and therefore
$$
\psi_k(t, \lambda) = e^{-2 \lambda^2 t / 9} \, \psi_k(\lambda).
$$
It remains to satisfy the initial condition, which reads
$$
1 = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sin ( k \varphi ) \int_0^\infty
J_{2k/3} \left(\frac{2 \lambda}{3} \, r^{3/2} \right) \psi_k(\lambda) \, d\lambda.
$$
Taking $\psi_k(\lambda) = \psi_k$ to be independent of $\lambda$, and then using the fact that
$$
\int_0^\infty J_\nu ( x ) \, dx = 1
$$
for all $\nu > 0$, we obtain a new equation on $\psi_k$:
$$
1 = \frac{3}{2 r^{3/2}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \psi_k \sin ( k \varphi ).
$$
To solve this, we use the $\sin$-Fourier expansion of $1$:
$$
1 = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin((2k-1) \varphi)}{2k-1}.
$$
Hence, letting
$$
\psi_{2k-1} = \frac{2 r^{3/2}}{3} \frac{4}{\pi(2k-1)}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\psi_{2k} = 0,
$$
we obtain
$$
u ( t, r, \varphi )
= \frac{8 r^{3/2}}{3 \pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin((2k-1)\varphi)}{2k-1} \int_0^\infty J_{2(2k-1)/3} \left( \frac{2\lambda}{3} \, r^{3/2} \right) \, e^{-2\lambda^2 t / 9} \, d\lambda. 
$$
Rather surprisingly, Mathematica was able to compute the last integral explicitly:
$$
\int_0^\infty J_{2(2k-1)/3} \left( \frac{2\lambda}{3} \, r^{3/2} \right) \, e^{-2\lambda^2 t / 9} \, d\lambda = \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 t}} \, e^{-r^3/4 t} I_{(2k-1)/3} \left( \frac{r^3}{4t} \right),
$$
where $I_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind. Therefore,
$$
u ( t, r, \varphi )
= \frac{4 r^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \, e^{-r^3/4t} \sum_{k=1}^\infty
\frac{\sin((2k-1)\varphi)}{2k-1} \, I_{(2k-1)/3} \left( \frac{r^3}{4t} \right).
$$
This is the final solution in $H$. It remains to change the variables back to $X$:
$$
r = |\xi| = | e^{-i \pi / 3} ( z - ( 1 + i ) )^{2/3} | = ( (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 )^{1/3}
$$
and
$$
\varphi = \arg \xi = \arg e^{-i\pi/3} (z-(1+i))^{2/3} = -\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \, \arg(x-1, y-1),
$$
where $\arg(x, y)$ has its branch cut along $\{ x > 0, y = 0 \}$ and goes to zero from above as $y \to 0+$, $x > 0$.
